# Identifying anchor element inside li protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to identify the anchor element under each li. This is what I have but I am getting no element found message. I tried with Id as well. Also, once I land on this page the page has carousel data image. For which i need to click till the end and validate. How do i do that?

```
element(by.css('u1 li a')).second().click(); - Method 1 tried
element(by.css('u1.centered li #day-tab')).click(); - Method 2 tired.
```

Why is that firepath recommended css and xpath don't work when used in protractor? I want to start using protractor but these limitations makes me think if I have to switch to using Python like most of our frameworks

```
 <ul class="centered"><li ng-show="showTab.now" ui-sref-active="active" class=""><a ui-sref="app.monitoring.real-time" id="now-tab" href="#/monitoring/real-time">Now</a></li><li ui-sref-active="active" class="active"><a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.day" id="day-tab" href="#/monitoring/historical/day">Day</a></li><li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.month" id="month-tab" href="#/monitoring/historical/month">Month</a></li><li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.year" id="year-tab" href="#/monitoring/historical/year">Year</a></li><li ng-show="showTab.lifetime" ui-sref-active="active" class=""><a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.lifetime" id="lifetime-tab" href="#/monitoring/historical/lifetime">Lifetime</a></li></ul>
```

Comment: I used all these to identify day tab. Nothing works. Is protractor buggy? or I am unable to follow - I don't understand Sigh ! by.css('#day-tab')
by.css('a[href="#/monitoring/historical/day"]')
by.css('a[ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.day"]')
by.id('day-tab')
by.linkText('Day')

Comment: Is your **ul** element under some iFrame or something?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have u**1** and not u**l**

```
by.css('u1 li a'))
         ^
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I changed it to ul but still i get "Undefined is not a function" error message for this it block

Comment: I really do not know protractor, but shouldn't it be `element.all(by.css('ul li a')).get(1).click();`